How to initialize a generic class that implements Comparable
The essence is quite simple:
I have a container class that contains a Map with elements that implement the Compable interface.
At the same time, the container class itself also implements the Compable interface. It looks like this:
public class Unit<V extends Comparable<? super V>> implements Comparable<Unit<V>>{

    @Setter
    private Map<String, V> params;

    @Override
    puplic int compareTo(Unit<V> u){
        ...
    }
    ...
}

Right now my calling code looks like this and it works:
Unit unit1 = new Unit<>;
Map<String, Comparable> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("First", 123);
params.put("Second", "ABS");
params.put("Third", 'a');

unit1.setParams(params);

Is there some way to specify specific types in the calling code?
I want to avoid "Raw use of parameterized class"
I tried to use '?' characters, but then I would have to change the Unit class and I would not be able to call the compareTo() method

There is no way to do this in a compile-time safe way. You can not demand that the container contains comparable objects and at the same time retain the information with what exactly they are comparable. Unless you fix all contained values to be comparable with the same kind of objects.
I.e. it is not possible to put strings, ints, dogs and whatever into the container, then retrieve them and retain the information the value you just got is a dog and can only be compared to other dogs.

Id suggest you explain why you want to create such a class and then people can propose alternative, better approaches.

@zabuzard "retain the information the value you just got is a dog and can only be compared to other dogs" - actualy, can i retain the information the value i just got is SOMETHING and can only be compared to SAME SOMETHING?

@Zabuzard
As for the goals: I decided to make an abstract comparator, inside which I can store N parameters. And I won't know anything about their type except that they are comparable. The only thing I want is that at the compilation level, only Compable parameters can be added to these N parameters, and nothing more. The comparator class itself will contain several methods that use the compareTo method on the internal collection with parameters.

"value i just got is SOMETHING and can only be compared to SAME SOMETHING" - no, you cannot. that would require you to define and capture one generic type per value you want to put into it. See, the thing is that when you write V, there is only one V. So it looks at your definition and the only type that can be given which would allow strings, ints and dogs is literally Comparable<? extends Object>. So you are throwing away pretty much any type information as the only type that satisfies all conditions at once is Object. You cannot get this compile-time safe in Java, only runtime.

This sounds like a potential XY problem.  You may want to reconsider your design.

Yes, you're right, it does sound logical
